# I am near I am far

Tags: riddle

> I am near, I am far
>
> I am big, I am small
>
> I can't see nor can I talk.
>
> In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.
>
> Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?
>
> I'm not behind your back

What am I?

Edit:
The riddle has an accepted answer but as some people pointed out the riddle might be a bit too broad.

Here are additional lines to help narrow the riddle possible solution:

> I'm not in abstract but am one
>
> I am not real but can think of as inside one
>
> Love the art in all colors and shapes.
>
> I am a rule of time and space
>
> Please I beg help me back inside the Frame.

Comment: This riddle has attracted a lot of different answers. You might want to [edit] it to narrow the scope a bit and ensure there's only one correct answer, before people start voting to close it as "too broad".

Comment: Is there some negative connotation to upvoting a question? This has a lot of upvotes for answers.

Comment: everytime I read this riddle all I can think of is this: https://youtu.be/iZhEcRrMA-M?t=14s

Comment: Sorry, I just don't think the accepted answer fits the riddle very well. And my suggestion of BEAUTY seems to fit even the additional lines at least as well as the intended answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> Distance

I am near, I am far

> Close or far, distance is

I am big, I am small

> Close or far, distance is perceived

I can't see nor can I talk.

> Distance is seen and perceived but doesn't speak

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> Distance makes things larger or smaller

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?

> Telescopes or microscopes, distance is still there but perceived opposite

I'm not behind your back

> You can't perceive distance behind you

Comment: I'll accept this answer, but for me the solution was... perspective which is the basically same as distance with a few minor modifications to the lines of the riddle.
Good Job

Answer (score 11):

Are you

> Eye floaters (little piece of dust or something on my eye) ?

I am near, I am far

> you seem far but you are actually very near

I am big, I am small

> you seem big but are actually very small

I can't see nor can I talk.

> you are a piece of dust

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> you sure do

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?

> you are always in my vision so i cannot miss you

I'm not behind your back

> clearly not

Comment: You're missing a line of the original riddle in your answer - clearly still a good fit but just FYI :)

Answer (score 5):

Possibly

> BEAUTY?

*I am near, I am far*
*I am big, I am small*

> Beautiful people/objects can be near or far, big or small; these things are irrelevant to their beauty.

*I can't see nor can I talk.*

> Clearly.

*In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.*

> "Beauty is in the eye of the beholder". And it can certainly affect people's minds.

*Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?*

> You might look at something beautiful and then miss it when you're no longer near it.

*I'm not behind your back*

> Beauty can only be detected when you're looking at it.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Footstep

I am near, I am far

> One step will be near to you and another one far

I am big, I am small

> It can also be big and small

I can't see nor can I talk.

> Of Course

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> You will always watch where your footstep is. With every step, you'll get closer to your destination.

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?
I'm not behind your back

> You can watch your footstep and then step back, your footsteps will be in front of you, not behind.

Comment: +1 nice one, but no cigar

Answer (score 3):

You are

> online chatter.

Feels so near but actually really far.
Big and Small.

> Friend's  smile feels so big but actually is very small 12×12 pixels.

Can't see or Talk

> in real but reading the text makes you hear and see things

In eyes and mind

> of chatter.
> All the imagination builds that transforms how the mind thinks snd heart feels

watch closely and step back you can see but can't touch

> yes missed ya

I am not behind your back

> because must be on front to read it.

Comment: (1) Please use spoiler markdown.  (2) Please quote the actual riddle when you respond to it.  Where did "you can see but can't touch" come from?  (3) Please use complete sentences, where applicable, and, in general, try to improve the quality of your explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> A refection in the mirror?

*I am near, I am far*

*I am big, I am small*

> A refection could be big or small, depending on stand near or far from a mirror.

*I can't see nor can I talk.*

> Obviously, a reflection can neither see nor talk, it is all by ourselves.

*In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.*

> A reflection can only be "found" through our own eyes.
>  
>  The appearance from the reflection do affect one's mood more or less.

*Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?*

> I'm not sure about this line, but I would say that people could make a close look on one of their body parts - when sqeezing acnes, doing makeup, even check the wound - then look back to check the whole face or body.

*I'm not behind your back*

> Another guess: unless with multiple mirrors placed in certain angle, we can't see a reflection from behind.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> my shadow?

I am near, I am far
I am big, I am small

> It depends of inclination of the sun (or other light sources)

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> Ii is not a concrete thing, it is only an effect of illumination (you can see). Shadows are a typical "scary" element in films, and childre (feeble minds) are scaried of their own shadows, like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K0R7oRYoEaM)

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?

> It is almost impossible to hit with a step my shadow, because it moves with my feet

I'm not behind your back

> Again it could be on one side or in front of me, it depends!

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Mountain?

I am near, I am far
I am big, I am small

> Mountain can be near or far. also, it big or small.

I can't see nor can I talk

> It can't see nor talk.

In your eyes I reside and affect your
feeble mind.

> Peoples like beauty of mauntain.

Watch closely and then step back, did
you miss me? I'm not behind your back

> You might look at something beautiful mountain
>  place and then miss it when you're no longer
>  near it.

Answer (score 2):

My answer

> Darkness

I am near, I am far

> Darkness can be near(Dusk) or far(noon)

I am big, I am small

> Darkness has no size. Can be big or small.

I can't see nor can I talk

> Self explanatory

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> Dark pupil in our eyes. And, people are generally afraid of Darkness

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me? I'm not behind your back

> We sort of have to watch and walk carefully in the darkness.

I am not behind your back

> Of course, it is in front of us.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was a **eye floaters** but unfortunately it doesn't accept.

So it might be

> **Vision**

I am near, I am far

> Yes,you can look far as well as near

I am big, I am small

> vision can be BIG and small

I can't see nor can I talk.

> It is vision

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> This line remind me of Steve jobs(RIP)

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?

> Don't miss your vision(Watch closely)

I'm not behind your back

> TRUE

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Glasses/Spectacles.

I am near, I am far

> Depends whether you have positive eye sight or negative.

I am big, I am small

> size of glasses

I can't see nor can I talk.

> It is eye who sees not the glasses.

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> Visualization affects the mind and glasses are all the time on.

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?

> if eye sighten, can't see without it.

I'm not behind your back

> Of course, not behind the back.

Answer (score 1):

You are

> Nose

I am near, I am far

> When you look to your nose, it could be near or far(while looking in mirror).

I am big, I am small

> size of nose is different for most of us.

I can't see nor can I talk.

> Yes. You can smell.

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> Try visualizing your nose by bringing your eyes together and your mind gets zzzzzzzzz!!!!!!!!!.

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?

> focus your eyes and look at nose and again look away, you will miss it in your vision.

I'm not behind your back

> Of course, not behind the back.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are:

> contact lens

I am near, I am far:

> You stay in my eyes, but I am unable to see you like you are so far

I am big, I am small:

> You are all the world with my eyes, but you are small

I can't see nor can I talk.

> You help me see but you are unable to see and talk

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> Without you, I think it's so hard to see

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?

> When drop you, I have to watch closely and step back to find you

I'm not behind your back

> You're always in front of me

Answer (score 0):

Are you

> Breasts

I am near, I am far

> For women their breasts are always near, for men breasts are sometimes far and sometimes near.

I am big, I am small

> [Big](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_Parton) and [Small](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cameron_Diaz)

I can't see nor can I talk.

> No mouth to speak with!

In your eyes I reside and affect your feeble mind.

> I'm always looking at them, staring, drooling, and not really thinking.

Watch closely and then step back, did you miss me?

> Yes, I do this too.

I'm not behind your back

> Breasts are on the *front*, not the back.